# Поиск строк и символов в Python из web страницы. Как реализовать?

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, строки

Само задание взято отсюда: https://stepik.org/lesson/209719/step/2?unit=183222
Ссылка https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python содержит статью с Википедии про язык Python. В этой статье есть теги code, которыми выделяются конструкции на языке Python. Вам нужно найти все строки, содержащиеся между тегами `<code>` и `</code>` и найти те строки, которые встречаются чаще всего и вывести их в алфавитном порядке, разделяя пробелами.

Например, если исходный текст страницы выглядел бы так:

```
<code>a</code>
<a>bracadabr</a>
<code>c</code>
<code>b</code>
<code>b</code>
<code>c</code>
```

то в ответ надо было бы ввести строку "b c"
Как я это решил:

```
import re
from urllib.request import urlopen

html = urlopen ("https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python").read().decode("utf-8")
m = ['a-z']
a = re.findall((r'<code>[a-b]</code>'), str)
print(a)
```

**Всё бы хорошо, но выдает ошибку:** *expected string or bytes-like object*

С чем это может быть связано?

Comment: С тем, что скопировали и не попытались понять, что скопировали?)

Answer (score 3):

```
a = re.findall((r'<code>[a-b]</code>'), str)
```

`str` - это такой тип данных в питоне, а вы пытаетесь в нём что-то найти как в переменной, поэтому и возникает ошибка:

```
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Искать надо в скачанной вами страничке `html`. И искать надо произвольный текст между тегами, причём в "не жадном" режиме, и ещё нас интересует только этот текст, без самих тегов, итого строчка кода для поиска должна быть такая:

```
a = re.findall((r'<code>(.*?)</code>'), html)
```

Остальное решение не пишу, хоть что-то постарайтесь сделать сами.